# QR-Code of Death - Javascript Barcode-API failure

Tags: qr-code

Currently I am trying to include a simple QR-code scanner in my APP.
(API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BarcodeDetector )

It works excellent on all my Mobile Devices (with Chrome 121 on Adroid 14).
But THIS ONE example QR-Code from Wikipedia kills the BarcodeDetector API:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Japan-qr-code-billboard.jpg

A commercial QR-Code Scanner tells me, the content is "MEBKM:TITLE:TrPÑwZTI;URL:http://sagasou.mobi;;"

Any ideas, what went wrong or how to solve? It seems to be an internal Error of the BarcodeDetector API.

Thanks,
Jo